# Unmasking Parasite Domains

Tags: javascript, redirect

Found some spammers masking our site with their domains.

-ourdomain.com 
-theirmaskeddomain.com opens our site and they also add a suspicious code in the page. Their plan is perhaps to get our content indexed through their domain and then exploit the visitors.

I am hoping to write a code which does this:

> On page load, 
>   if page URL set in broweser is NOT ourdomain.com*
>   Redirect user to ourdomain.com*

I will appreciate if someone can help with the piece of code or come up with another better idea.

Thanks a lot

**Update:** Tried frame busting option which doesnt work.

Comment: What do you mean "opens our site"? Do you mean they are using FRAMEs (or IFRAMEs)? If so you might want to check out any number of the [frame busting solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed) on SO.

Comment: `if (window.top.location.hostname != 'example.com') window.top.location.href = 'http://example.com';`

Comment: Thanks guys .. here are the two URLs original (https://www.topbargains.com.au/) masked (http://topbargain.org/)

Comment: @KBS Put the relevant code in your question.

Comment: @Brad I don't know how to code .. this is what I need help with