# How to detect whether a HTML file is opened in browser or some Application Software?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to do some changes in my HTML file based on whether it is opened in browser or Some Desktop Application.

Till now I've tried this in my script:

```
alert(navigator.appName);
alert(navigator.appCodeName);
alert(navigator.platform);
```

But the values are coming same whether the HTML file is opened in browser or some application Software.

How can i set a variable which toggle its value from 0 to 1 when opened in application Software and vice versa.

PS: Application Software like Matlab, MS Office , Britanica Encyclopedia etc.

Comment: What do you mean 'open in desktop Application'? Double click on it and open it with file protocol?

Comment: Browsers tend to be desktop applications. Not entirely sure what you're asking.

Comment: @laruiss : consider Netbeans IDE as a desktop application. In that i have different iframes. Lets say in left iframe i have hyperlinks. when i click on that hyperlink, its respective HTML file gets opened in right iframe. what i want to do is to differentiate whether my HTML file is opened in this kind of desktop application or in Browser.

Comment: @phuzi : I updtaed the question. its not desktop application its application software.

Comment: Those “desktop applications” won’t have their own implementation of a rendering engine, but simple embed a browser that is installed on the system as a component, and let it do the work – so for most navigator properties I think it is to be expected that you get the same values as you would from that browser when it is used “stand-alone”.

Comment: Perhaps looking a `window` properties might be more successful; although I can’t tell you which ones specifically might accomplish what you want. I’d suggest that instead of alerting single values, you go through the window properties using a `for in` loop, and contact all them as text, that you then output in a texarea or something – and then look for differences.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, you can't.

Longer answer, to some extent. What you need to do is make a list of differences in each desktop apps implementation, based on known flaws, missing/existing properties, user agent flavours and so on (some of this called "browser spoofing"), to be able to sort them out. It will still be possible to trick this if one want to though.

Normally there is another way of dealing with the differences, the question is what is the different behaviour you want between the 2?

As a sample, and if you still need/insists to detect this, there is device detection libraries which can help as a start, like https://51degrees.com/device-detection

I still recommend to find another way to solve it.

**UPDATE**

As it is easy to create a desktop app and return the values needed for your page to believe it is a normal browser, I think the best solution is to ask the user on first page hit if they are on a normal browser or not (the one who is not will normally know) and then store in a cookie/set a flag and act upon what the user selected.

I mean it is easy to cheat your page either way so better trust on user selection.

Comment: I want to hide all buttons of my HTML file when it is opened in any application software or desktop application and to show all buttons when opened in any browser.

Comment: So you mean that desktop app users will have limited access to your site?

Comment: Exactly. For that i need a flag which toggle its value when opened in browser or in some Application software. And based on that flag value i can change the visibility of my button. I just need a way to toggle my flag value.

Comment: So to save you a lot of headache I updated my answer with a suggestion. If this still doesn't work for you, you need to go the long road of sniffing...

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 step verification for such cases as devices are getting quite varied. First you can detect devices by media queries strings using `innerWidth` property. And then you can apply second filter matched by protocol it supports.

Secondly, this SO question might help [Frame Buster Buster ... buster code needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed)