# iframe automatically redirects to destination page instead of staying on the page it was framed

Tags: iframe

I am trying to iframe a site:

https://dms.paperlessolutions.net/dms/start.jsp#75c8

I have permission but when I embed this into a site the site automatically redirects to the actual page... I would like to stay in the iframe I created.

Does anyone know what is going on here?   I have asked their tech team and they say it should work?

Comment: its shows the message invalid link - your link is not working.

Comment: Sorry the link was working they have a wonky session expiration "feature" https://dms.paperlessolutions.net/dms/start.jsp#b8e1

Comment: this link isn't working too. i think it's a session problem but try my answer - and don't forget to rate and set the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is some kind of script which cause this behavior.

Try to add `sandbox` to your `iframe` - for more info on how to use sandbox in an more specific way like this `sandbox=""` with attributes read the following [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp). It's easy!

Comment: Thanks - I tried this - and it did prevent the iframe from redirecting but it also shows blank on the page.  For those who have this issue it is commonly known as frame busting.   Here is a good stack article on it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed?rq=1