# How to sanitize html blob uploads in python in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sanitization

If HTML is uploaded into Google App Engine with an intent to be serviced into an iframe, what is the best way to sanitize it (e.g. remove script and other malicious html) ?

I am thinking of

```
        reader = blobstore.BlobReader(binfo.key())
        value = reader.read()
        newHtml = lxml.html.clean.Cleaner().clean_html (value)
        #save newHtml as the blob in google cloud store to be served.
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to do this and any help is much appreciated.

NB: It will also be great if there is a way to remove anchors or make anchors(or sources) non-relative and secure http, etc.. (or just completely disallow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a challenging problem to solve well, since there are so many ways in which HTML can be injected with malicious content. `script` elements are perhaps the most well-known/common, but `form`, `input`, and `img` elements can also be abused. There's also the ability for malicious JS to be included in almost any element via event handlers.  [More information about XSS from OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)), to get you started.

Since you're using Python, here are a few libraries for sanitizing HTML that may be useful for you to try.

- [bleach](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bleach)
- [html-sanitizer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html-sanitizer/)
- [sanitize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sanitize)

For what it's worth, hosting user-provided HTML in an `iframe` is one way to prevent malicious content from accessing the app you're hosting (although you may want to take steps to prevent `iframe` breakout), but you may want to make it clear to your users that the content hosted there cannot always be trusted.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Many thanks. I am using lxml.clean and it is stripping out a lot of this and seems to be one popular sanitizer.. But I will also checkout the others you mentioned. Btw, when you say 'iframe breakout' what do you mean ? Also I am thinking of 'sandbox'ing the iframe - is that generally recommended in such cases ?

Comment: Yeah, [sandboxed iframes](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/) should give you the ability to lock things down a bit more.  You might also consider setting [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options), if those work for your use-case.

Here's some more information:
* [Clickjacking Defense Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet)
* [Recent SO thread about frame-busting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed)