# Need to open new window from iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm running into a problem for a website I'm assisting a client with. They have a Clickfunnels survey form embedded on a webpage in an iframe.

The survey form has several different possible outcomes, but all responses go to 4 different pages depending on the options chosen.

When the user finishes the survey, they are redirected to the appropriate page based on the answers they selected.

The problem, is that when they are redirected the new page opens in the iframe instead of a new tab.

Normally I could do in and add a target blank to the link, but since the form was created in Clickfunnels, it's a little more complicated.

Is there a way to use javascript to add a function to the form upon submission to open in a new window?

Comment: Would frame busting work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed

Comment: Yes! That solved it! Thank you so much!